# How to calculate entropy of a random number?

Tags: random-number-generator, randomness, pseudo-random-function

I am having a set of random numbers and I want to calculate entropy of them. I searched many entropy calculation formula, but I didn't get it. Can you elaborate a little bit?

Comment: Many formulae?  Is there more than one?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what exactly you do not understand please?

Comment: If your numbers were auto correlated, that would be interesting.  Are they?

Comment: @Paul Uszak: you are right, there is not more that one applicable formula; there's none, for the reason in the second sentence in [that answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/51302/555).

Answer (score 9):

In a cryptographic sense this is not really possible. The entropy of the numbers is determined by the way they have been *chosen*. From only a list of numbers, say $(1, 2, 3, 4)$, we cannot *just* determine the entropy.

But if we instead say that we choose four numbers uniformly from 1 to 10, we *can* calculate the entropy. Recall the definition of (*Shannon*) entropy:

$$
H(X) = -\sum_{i=1}^n {\mathrm{P}(x_i) \log_b \mathrm{P}(x_i)}
$$

Here $X$ is the state (e.g. $(1, 2, 3, 4)$). The $x_i$ values are the *possible* states, e.g. $\{(1, 1, 1, 1), (1, 1, 1, 2), \ldots, (10, 10, 10, 10)\}$. $P(x_i)$ is the probability that the random number $X = x_i$. When the probability distribution is uniform, then the probabilities are all equal to $\frac{1}{n}$.

Notice that this is a calculation not over the state itself, but over *the probability distribution of all the possible states*. In other words: The entropy is determined not on what the numbers **are**, but how they are **chosen**.

[[More information on how entropy is actually calculated.]](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/374/45787)

It is possible to *estimate* (not calculate) the entropy of a series of data, but this is more relevant in the field of data processing. This is not relevant in cryptography.

Comment: And what is x exactly if the source isn't a CSPRNG?

Comment: I expanded the answer to elaborate $x$ and the other variables. Not sure if it is really clear. What do you think?

Comment: Usually in cryptography we are concerned with _min-entropy_, $-\max_i \log_2 P(x_i)$, not Shannon entropy, since it better reflects a smart adversary's chance at breaking a system, rather than a random uninformed adversary's chance at breaking it.  I also like to emphasize the interpretation that [a probability distribution formalizes either a _physical process_ or an adversary's _state of knowledge_](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/50289/49826).